# How can I refresh a UITableView while a user is re-arranging cells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an editable UITableView. While my user is re-arranging the cells, I want to be able to update the tableview because I get a funny situation when I re-arrange the bottom cell and insert it into the middle. It create an unwanted effect because the bottom row is rounded and the middle row should not be. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

To achieve this look I had to set the `backgroundView` of each `UITableViewCell`. The top and bottom ones are using a separate image than ones in the middle.

**UPDATED**:

I am not sure if I am missing any cases, because the images still get messed up when re-ordering.

```
for (NSIndexPath* visibleIndexPath in tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {
        UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath];

        //Top moving to middle rows
        if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row != sectionRows - 1) {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablemiddle55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Top moving to bottom
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1) {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebottom55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Top moving to top
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0) {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabletop55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Middle moving to top
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row != 0 && sourceIndexPath.row != sectionRows -1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabletop55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Middle moving to bottom
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row != 0 && sourceIndexPath.row != sectionRows -1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebottom55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Middle moving to middle
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row != 0 && sourceIndexPath.row != sectionRows -1 && 
                 proposedDestinationIndexPath.row != sectionRows -1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row !=0)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablemiddle55@2x.png"];
        }
        //Bottom moving to top
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabletop@2x.png"];
        }
        //Bottom moving to middle
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row != 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row != sectionRows - 1)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablemiddle@2x.png"];
        }
        //Bottom moving to bottom
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == sectionRows - 1)
        {
            ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebottom@2x.png"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the @2x suffix in `imageNamed`. It will be added automatically when needed.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to sidestep the problem by rounding the corners of the table view rather than the internal cells? It'd look and act differently, but could it be another reading of whatever style rules you are applying?

Comment: The tableview is rounded, I am just using custom graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is mostly wrong because of the `for {}`. As it stands right now, you do something like "if the destination is such and the source is such, modify all the currently visible cells". But anyway, this is not the main problem.

I must say, I've played a lot of time with the method `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:` before even attempting to answer this question. Now I feel more confident to write it.

For starters, using this method in conjunction with `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not a good choice if you don't know what's happening. Simply put, **even though the cells have shifted for the animation, the changes don't really affect the tableView until the user stops dragging the cell.**

For example, let's say that you have the cell at index 0 with the title `@"Hello"`, and the next cell with `@"World"`, if you start dragging the first cell downwards, the animation will move the cell "Hello" one row upwards, but calling `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` for the row at index 0 will always return the "Hello" cell. The tableView is unaffected until the tableView reorder ends, everything else is just eye-candy.

So, to answer your question, and to swap the images on the fly (as soon as the user moves the cell), you should do the following, for example, for the first row:

```
//Top moving to middle rows
if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row != 0)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:sourceIndexPath.section]];
    ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablemiddle55"];
}
```

One the user drags the row 0 downwards, it tells the row at 1 to swap its background to the top, as he will become the new top row. Similar cases must be considered for the bottom row,  or middle row becoming the first one. Also, the `for {}` with the visible cells is not necessary in this case.

**Edit:** Okay, I managed to make ALL the cases, it has some weird things here and there, but it works most of the time. The code here just changes the detailLabel to "First"/"Middle"/"Last", but that should be easy to change with a Find&Replace.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    //NSLog(@"%d -> %d (proposed)", sourceIndexPath.row, proposedDestinationIndexPath.row);

    NSInteger lastRow = [arrayWithContent count]-1;

    // Adjust the row being moved
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath].detailTextLabel.text = @"First";
    else if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == lastRow)
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath].detailTextLabel.text = @"Last";
    else
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath].detailTextLabel.text = @"Middle";

    // Top -> Middle
    if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Top -> Middle");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"First";
    }
    // Top -> Top (user is screwing around)
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Top -> Top");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Middle";
    }
    // Middle -> Top
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row > 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Middle -> Top");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Middle";
    }
    // Middle -> Bottom
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row < lastRow && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == lastRow)
    {
        NSLog(@"Middle -> Bottom");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Middle";
    }
    // Bottom -> Middle
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row == lastRow && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == lastRow-1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bottom -> Middle");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(lastRow-1) inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Last";
    }
    // Bottom -> Bottom (user is screwing around, AGAIN)
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row == lastRow && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == lastRow)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bottom -> Bottom");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(lastRow-1) inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Middle";
    }
    // Middle -> Top -> Middle (ugh)
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row > 0 && sourceIndexPath.row < lastRow && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Middle -> Top -> Middle");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"First";
    }
    // Middle -> Bottom -> Middle (ugh x2)
    else if (sourceIndexPath.row > 0 && sourceIndexPath.row < lastRow && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == lastRow-1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Middle -> Bottom -> Middle");
        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0]].detailTextLabel.text = @"Last";
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

Comment: No problem, I was curious on how to do it, so I just took your if-else into infinity and beyond. I still think there's a _better way_, maybe just forcing the correct cells to reload automatically. Also, in my tests, I noticed that a large table that requires scrolling might have problems when dragging the first row and moving it to the last spot (or the opposite), I think it's because how cells get reusably-enqueued once they are out of the visible area.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you simply need to change the background views of the cells that changed just like you did in `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
   //The rest of your stuff you need to do

   for (NSIndexPath* visibleIndexPath in self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows) {
       UITableViewCell* visibleCell [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath];
       if (visibleIndexPath.row == 0) ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabletop55.png"];
       else if (visibleIndexPath.row == [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:visibleIndexPath.section) {
           ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebottom55.png"];
       }
       else ((UIImageView *)cell.backgroundView).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tablemiddile55.png"];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Take a look at my updated question with code. Am I missing any cases?

Comment: I think you should change the background view in the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. Then after changing the data source and reloading the table view the cell's will automatically find it's background view.

Comment: You're changing only the source cell, you need to change every visible cells since they can possibly all change. Look at my answer : there's a for loop inside `self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`.

Comment: Thanks gcamp. I stuck my big if block inside of that for-loop but getting the same results. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer again. But I don't think you understood the code that I wrote, you need to change the background of every visible cells, *no mater what are sourceIndexPath and proposedDestinationIndexPath*. I don't know why you were checking for those in your if/else clauses, you need to look for `visibleIndexPath`.

Comment: I edited your code to match my names. Check it out. Unfortunately that doesn't change the behavior much. I am still getting not getting the background image to display correctly when moving from top-to-bottom etc etc.

Comment: Have you tried debugging, at all? Is `cell` nil, is `visibleIndexPath.count` == 0?

Comment: cell is not nil, and visibleIndexPath does not equal 0

Comment: There's something not going right with the assignation of the image to the background view. That's all I can say. I won't be debugging for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be updating your data array as the user edits it. Once you update your new array, then you can call `reloadData` to refresh the UITableView.

Comment: That doesn't work because when I try to re-arrange the cells, the tableview will refresh and the user won't be able to move the cell to the proposed destination.

Comment: then what you eed to do is save the new order of the data after the user is done editing.