# Background images for cells when reordering a custom grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created my own custom grouped UITableView. It is a table where the top cell uses "top.png" as background, the middle cells "middle.png" and the bottom cell "bottom.png".

I'm using

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
```

to change the background images of the cells when they are being dragged around during reordering. However, I can't seem to find a simple solution to this. However I try, I always end up with a really complex solution with a lot of if-cases, and it just feels really messy, over complex and like I don't cover all the cases. Is there a simple solution to this problem that I'm overseeing?

I've found "solutions" to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266568/how-can-i-refresh-a-uitableview-while-a-user-is-re-arranging-cells) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237360/reloading-custom-uitableviewcell-after-reordering-cells). But they are not complete and don't work with every case.

Special cases that should be handled, but that the two mentioned solutions don't handle:

- Move row around, then back to original position
- Move one row fast around the rows, scrolling down the tableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I think I've worked out a solution. From my tests it works fine in one section (tested with between two and about a dozen cells), but will need some modification if you're dragging cells between different sections. I haven't made those modifications yet since I don't need that functionality.

This method assumes you've implemented the delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

to set the initial backgrounds for the cells and that it's working correctly.

This method will update cells for their new position as they move

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {

    // Get the index paths of the cells above and below our current target cell
    NSIndexPath *higherPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:proposedDestinationIndexPath.row - 1 inSection:proposedDestinationIndexPath.section];
    NSIndexPath *lowerPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:proposedDestinationIndexPath.row + 1 inSection:proposedDestinationIndexPath.section];

    // Update our source cell to the appropriate image for its current position
    [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath] forRowAtIndexPath:proposedDestinationIndexPath];


    if (sourceIndexPath.row > proposedDestinationIndexPath.row) {
        // Source cell is below the target

        // Update the cell that was in our target position
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:proposedDestinationIndexPath] forRowAtIndexPath:lowerPath];

        // Ensure that any cell above our new target is refreshed if the cell is dragged back down the list
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:higherPath] forRowAtIndexPath:higherPath];

    } else if (sourceIndexPath.row < proposedDestinationIndexPath.row) {
        // Source cell is above the target

        // Update the cell that was in our target position
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:proposedDestinationIndexPath] forRowAtIndexPath:higherPath];

        // Ensure that any cell below our new target is refreshed if the cell is dragged back up the list
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lowerPath] forRowAtIndexPath:lowerPath];

    } else {
        // Source cell is the same as the target - cell is back in its original position

        // Update any cells below and above the position
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:higherPath] forRowAtIndexPath:higherPath];
        [self tableView:self.tableView willDisplayCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lowerPath] forRowAtIndexPath:lowerPath];
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

I came up with this while suffering from the flu so I may have made some silly mistake in my explanations but I'm pretty confident this should work reliably, except for the single section limitation.

Comment: I've actually abandoned the grouped table approach in my project, so I can't test your solution. But I take your word that it works and accept it